# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/slots/[slot number]/power is changing value of PCIe configuration space register?

Tags: linux, kernel, pci

when doing

```
echo 1  > /sys/bus/pci/slots/[slot number]/power
```

will kernel change the value in some(or particular) register of PCIe configuration space of this device?

In my understanding, when a system ( PC ) power-on, the power already provide to PCIe devices, but kernel can still control some slot to be ON and OFF ( as the sysfs contorl command in this article), is that because kernel setting a register in PCIe configuration space which controls its power?

when we reading it, does that also read from a register in slot control register?

ex:

```
cat /sys/bus/pci/slots/[slot number]/power
```

Comment: Can you explain it more??

Comment: what is kernel done after executed this command?

Comment: change a value in slot control register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my tracing ( let me know if I am wrong )

power_write_file()
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/source/drivers/pci/hotplug/pci_hotplug_core.c#L95

```
slot->ops->disable_slot(slot);

ops->disable_slot = disable_slot;
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/source/drivers/pci/hotplug/pciehp_core.c#L107

```
static int disable_slot(struct hotplug_slot *hotplug_slot)
{
    struct slot *slot = hotplug_slot->private;

    return pciehp_sysfs_disable_slot(slot);
}
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/source/drivers/pci/hotplug/pciehp_core.c#L167

```
retval = pciehp_disable_slot(p_slot);

remove_board(struct slot *p_slot)
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/source/drivers/pci/hotplug/pciehp_ctrl.c#L135

finally, we got:

```
void pciehp_power_off_slot(struct slot *slot)
{
    struct controller *ctrl = slot->ctrl;

    pcie_write_cmd(ctrl, PCI_EXP_SLTCTL_PWR_OFF, PCI_EXP_SLTCTL_PCC);
    ctrl_dbg(ctrl, "%s: SLOTCTRL %x write cmd %x\n", __func__,
         pci_pcie_cap(ctrl->pcie->port) + PCI_EXP_SLTCTL,
         PCI_EXP_SLTCTL_PWR_OFF);
}
```

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.10/source/drivers/pci/hotplug/pciehp_hpc.c#L551

```
#define  PCI_EXP_SLTCTL_PWR_OFF        0x0400 /* Power Off */
#define PCI_EXP_SLTCTL      24  /* Slot Control */
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d01e12dd3f4227f1be5d7c5bffa7b8240787bec1/include/uapi/linux/pci_regs.h#L594

0x0400 ==> 10000000000 # bit 10 == 1 ==> Power Controller Control register is 1 in Slot Control Register ( offset 18h == 24 )

according to PCIe spec about Power Controller Control register:

```
0b Power On
1b Power Off
```

therefore, the answer is yes,

kernel will change Power Controller Control register in Slot Control Register.